# md-autocomplete dropdown size not stable

Tags: angularjs, size, md-autocomplete

I'm using an existing md-autocomplete input.

My issue is that the size of the dropdown is variable.
It may have a lot of result in the dropdown and still it limits the size of the md-autocomplete to 2. And we can scroll to access all of them.

But it's not what it should.

How can i force it to show the same size all the time ? Or a true automatic size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set style:

```
.md-virtual-repeat-scroller{
   height: 506px; 
  max-height: 506px; 
  min-height: 506px; 
}

md-virtual-repeat-container{
  height: 506px; 
  max-height: 506px; 
  min-height: 506px; 
}
```

<kbd>[Demo Codepen](https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/dzqbYP)</kbd>

Comment: I tried it with 56px and 500px but there is no difference.
The first time i use it the dropdown is very long then it's always 2 items long.

Comment: The md-autocompletion one or the grid ?

Comment: @AlbanMartinez didnt understand your question

Comment: I saw you answered both my posts ^^. The second one is the one about an ng-grid.
Your css works fine. It changed an other md-autocomplete i wanted to keep untouched but i will use an id or something.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It seems i can't use id to separate them. How can i apply your css to one and not the other ? They have the save md-virtual-repeat.

Comment: Add some class to parent and add class name to css